# Jquery - Sum of cloned elements won't work with input from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clone').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest('.groupcontainer');
    target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target);
  });

  $('.input').on('input',function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val() * $(this).parent().children('.input2').val());
  });

  $('.input2').on('input', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val() * $(this).parent().children('.input').val());
  });
});  

$(document).on('change', '.grouptotal', function(){
  var sum = 0;
    $('.grouptotal').each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $('#subtotal').val(sum);
});
```

My issue is that I need `#subtotal` to add every instance of `.grouptotal`, but `#subtotal` is not updating when it gets it's input from

```
$('.input').on('input',function(){
  $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val() * 
  $(this).parent().children('.input2').val());
  });

$('.input2').on('input', function(){
  $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val() *   
  $(this).parent().children('.input').val());
  });
```

`#subtotal` will update if I manually put numbers in `.grouptotal` however.  Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/se7og7k7/2/).  It looks kind of sloppy but it gives the idea.

Quantity * System will automatically update my `.grouptotal`

How do I make it so `#subtotal` will take the `.grouptotal`s and add them up automatically?  I've tried changing `$(document).on('change', '.grouptotal', function(){` "change" to 'input' and a couple others, but no luck.

Also, it must work if the `#clone` button is clicked to duplicate the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the value programatically with `val('value')` the `change` event isn't fired, you have to actually trigger it

```
$(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val( $(this).val() ).trigger('change')
```

Comment: I get it, but maybe I'm not doing it right?  Now my quantity * system price isn't updating in grouptotal.  `$('.input').on('input',function(){
     $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val().trigger('change') * $(this).parent().children('.input2').val());
   });
 
  $('.input2').on('input', function(){
     $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val().trigger('change') * $(this).parent().children('.input').val());
   });`

Comment: This worked, played around with it.  Added the .trigger like this: `$(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').trigger('change')`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this again.  Evidently, changing the grouptotal values programmatically does not trigger the change event.  I would have thought it would, so your code looked right to me.  To fix, however, I added an explicit trigger of '.grouptotal'.  You can see the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylivan/se7og7k7/4/).

just add the code:

```
('.grouptotal').change();
```

to both of your handlers that sum from inputs.  that might not be the solution you are looking for, but it seems to work

Comment: Thanks, but when I get rid of the + it doesn't add, it just concatenates the `.grouptotal`s instead of summing them up.

Comment: seems to work fine for me, check out the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/se7og7k7/3/

Comment: sorry - I misunderstood your question - I see now.  let me relook!

Comment: Great!  Glad to help!